# How to run commands on shell through python

Tags: python, subprocess

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calling an external command in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)

I want to run commands in another directory using python.

What are the various ways used for this and which is the most efficient one?

What I want to do is as follows,

```
cd dir1
execute some commands
return 
cd dir2
execute some commands
```

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python where this topic was extensively discussed.

Comment: did you try anything? Do any research?

Answer (score 8):

Naturally if you only want to run a (simple) command on the shell via python, you do it via the `system` function of the `os` module. For instance:

```
import os
os.system('touch myfile')
```

If you would want something more sophisticated that allows for even greater control over the execution of the command, go ahead and use the `subprocess` module that others here have suggested.

For further information, follow these links:

- [Python official documentation on `os.system()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system)
- [Python official documentation on the `subprocess` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)

Comment: `os.system()` will run in /bin/sh . If your command (script) requires bash, this won't work.

Answer (score 4):

If you want more control over the called shell command (i.e. access to stdin and/or stdout pipes or starting it asynchronously), you can use the `subprocess`module:

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen('ls -al', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
```

See also [`subprocess` module documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
os.system("/dir/to/executeble/COMMAND")
```

for example

```
os.system("/usr/bin/ping www.google.com")
```

if ping program is located in "/usr/bin"

Naturally you need to import the os module.

os.system does not wait for any output, if you want output, you should use

subprocess.call or something like that

Comment: someone told me we have subprocess.call , os.system... which one is usefull??

Comment: Depending on what you need. If you want to just start something in the shell in the back, use os.system. Use subprocess.call or something similar if you want to wait for the results from the process.. subprocess.Popen, works quite similarly as popen in c

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Python Subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) ,which offers many modules to execute commands, checking outputs and receive error messages etc.