# How to run shell commands inside python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I need to create AWS lambda function to execute the python program.
I need to incorporate the following shell command in it.

```
curl https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json | jq -r '.prefixes[] | select(.region=="ap-southeast-1") | .ip_prefix'
```

Could someone guide me on this.

Comment: Does this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/how-to-execute-a-program-or-call-a-system-command-from-python Same here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14457756/how-to-run-commands-on-shell-through-python

Comment: This smells like an X/Y problem – you really shouldn't shell out to `curl` and `jq` to download and parse JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simply shell out to curl and jq to get that data,

```
import subprocess

data = subprocess.check_output("""curl https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json | jq -r '.prefixes[] | select(.region=="ap-southeast-1") | .ip_prefix'""", shell=True)
```

but you really probably shouldn't do that since e.g. there's no guarantee you have `curl` and `jq` in the Lambda execution environment (not to mention the overhead).

Instead, if you have the [`requests`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library,

```
import requests

resp = requests.get("https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json")
resp.raise_for_status()
prefixes = {
    r["ip_prefix"]
    for r in resp.json()["prefixes"]
    if r["region"] == "ap-southeast-1"
}
```

Comment: Many thanks. Is their a way for me to store all the IPs in a single file

Comment: In general, yes, of course you can write them into a file. However, you can't write files in lambda functions.

Comment: Understood. I need to fetch these output IPs and store them in a file, later dump the file to S3 for further processing.

Comment: So you need to store them in S3? Fine, that you _can_ do; the `boto3` library is the go-to S3 client for Python.